# How to prevent adding new lines in style tag html files via Atom-Beautify

Tags: html, atom-editor

I use atom-beautify to format html, but it always adds new lines in css style, after each style.
How can I set atom-beautify to keep the same state what I wrote.

What I want:

[image: atom-beautify html formatting]

The current format result:

[image: atom-beautify html formatting]

Answer (score 0):

## Package Settings

You can disable that in the package settings (`Settings / PackagesAtom / Beautify`):

[image]

As you can see, it's disabled by default.

## Config file

Alternatively, have a look at the [JS Beautify options](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options). You can specify your preferred rules in a `.jsbeautifyrc` file in your project root.